# "Access denied" with a custom list form and list with unique permissions

Tags: permissions, list-form

I have created a list which has unique permissions. It’s an order submission form. I want end users to be able to place order using this list form.  The whole site has only read permissions but this list should have contribute permissions so that end users can submit the form but every time i try to submit the form as an end user, i get Access Denied error. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce your problem here.

These are the steps I followed.

- Logged in a Admin user
- Create a site
- Edit Site Permissions
- Stop Inheriting Permissions,
- Remove all permissions (I am admin so I will still be able to access the site)
- Grant Read Permission to "User A"
- Create a Custom List
- Edit List Permissions
- Stop Inheriting Permissions
- Grant Contribute rights to "User A"
- Log Out
- Log in as "User A"
- I have read access to the site
- When I visit the list I see the add item button
- Create an Item
- Save.

No access denied error is displayed and the item is created.

When you get the access denied page can you check the URL to see exactly which page SharePoint was trying to access?

Maybe there will be more information in the SharePoint log file.

Answer (score 0):

try putting insert code in

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{

//your insert code

});